# Flutter convert part of QuizesBloc state to QuizState

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have a List<Quiz> objects and I added these to QuizesState(Bloc is QuizesBloc) and displaying the listview. If I click on any single Quiz I want to add that particular Quiz object to another state called QuizState(Bloc is QuizBloc). How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Add a selectedQuizId to your QuizesState.

(2) In your QuizesView (with the list of quizzes) add a BlocListener, listening to changes in QuizesState and if selectedQuizId is not null.

(3) navigate to a quiz route and provide selectedQuizId as an arugument

(4) create your QuizPage like this

```dart
class QuizPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuizPage({super.key});

  static Route<void> route(String? quizId) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      fullscreenDialog: true,
      builder: (context) => BlocProvider(
        create: (context)
        { 
        return QuizBloc(
            quizId: quizId,
            repository: context.read<QuizRepository>()
          )..add(QuizRequested());
        },
        child: const QuizPage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const QuizView();
  }
}
```

(5) pick up the quizId upon initializing the QuizBloc